# Few large images versus many small images

Tags: image, http, httprequest, page-load-time, image-size

I have always thought that it is best, when forced to use images in websites, to use the smallest images as possible. However, if that means using several small images to get the same result as one large image, I am unsure if this is then also not good because of making more HTTP requests.

What is the best approach in this case?

- Few large images = larger files to download
- Many small images = small files to download but many HTTP requests

When I say "many", I just mean 4 or 5 as opposed to the one large image.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

Just to let you know the difference in file size that I am talking about. In one case that I have come across today:

- Using the one large image = 1 request @ 11.3KB
- Using five small images = 5 requests @ 1.2KB (total)

Comment: Are you referring to different sizes of the same image, or different images put into one large image file, and positioned with CSS?

Comment: I think you are asking me if I am talking about sprites. No I'm not - I'm talking about one image that could be broken down into 4 or 5 very small images and then used alongside CSS background colours and repeating backgrounds, as opposed to using the full image.

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a decent question to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using many small images rather than one large image.

The reason for this is that if, on one page, you have a content background with rounded corners, and its all done as one image that will be better than having multiple HTTP requests for the same effect.

However, if on another page, you have a similar content background, then theyre will have to be another large image.

If the first background was broken down into multiple images, theres a chance the 2nd background may be able to use some of these images, saving multiple HTTP requests. For example, if both images have rounded corners, the second page could use the same rounded corners, and just a new image for the main content area.

Comment: Latency rather than the size of the images (within reason) is the most import factor here. You're loading the first page with the latency of the extra requests that a subsequent page may need and the visitor may not ever go to the second page. In the original question the latency of the extra-requests (especially if slow-start  is involved) will probably outweigh the extra bandwidth used.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise using 1 big image instead of several smaller ones.

The total size (in bytes) is gonna be (roughly) the same wether or not you use 1 big file or several smaller ones. But as you already pointed out, you're making more HTTP handshakes which will slow things down.

For multiple websites I work on, we try to combine multiple same-kinded images into 1 image file, just to cut back on HTTP Handshakes.

Comment: In the case I am talking about, I am referring to using 4 or 5 very small images, some of which are then used as repeating backgrounds and others for things like rounded corners etc. (I know I could use CSS3 for rounded corners, but in some cases the round corners do make a big difference to the design and losing them on browsers that don't support CSS3 is a problem). And then I use background colours using CSS where possible. So I try to use CSS where possible and then only use the images if necessary. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You absolutely want to use one image, and use "Sprite" techniques to combine multiple images into one. Watch with Fiddler to see if you also save bytes-on-wire by losing HTTP response header overhead. You should also go read Steve Souders' "Building High Performance Websites" for other tips.

Comment: Yes I agree using sprites would be best, so probably the answer I'm looking for is "neither" really - neither one big or many small images. What I was referring to in my question is the type of large images that should (in my opinion) be broken into smaller chunks but I was just wondering how bad large file size was in comparison to more http requests.

Answer (score 1):

As EricLaw points out in Johan's answer; another solution would be to combine the smaller images into one image which you can then manipulate with CSS Sprites.  This solution has the following benifits:

- reduced the number of HTTP requests (since you're only requesting one
  image)
- allows caching for reuse with different backgrounds (as pointed out
  in Curt's answer)